# Android - Move a single instance of a View between Parent Views

Tags: android, singleton

For an important reason, i'm required to keep *only* a single instance of a View in the entire application.

Within the application there will be multiple parent views, (each displayed only once at at time). And I need to move the child view around - to the currently active parent.

I tried doing the following:

```
if (view_to_move_around != null) {

    ViewGroup oldParent = (ViewGroup) view_to_move_around.getParent();
    if (oldParent != null) {
        oldParent.removeView(view_to_move_around);
    }

} else {

    // Initialise the View

}

newParent.addView(view_to_move_around)
```

However, that method didn't seem to work? Completely stuck at this point.

Comment: Have you considered making the child view visible and setting the parent views to gone or invisible when that child view needs to be seen?

Comment: That wouldn't work as it needs to be contained within a parent. For visual purposes.

Comment: Can you use a fragment containing the child view?

Comment: Have never used Fragments (i'm an iOS developer at heart) Can they be added to Views?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the code in the "if" clause?

Comment: @Jonathan: [Read up on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) because they're essential to building a more complex and functional UI in Android. You need to create a ViewGroup within your main activity and then you can call a Fragment (with its own defined View) within that ViewGroup.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my question will be "What do you mean it's not working?" Are you getting an exception? It is not being displayed properly? Does it execute without issue, but is not displaying? Does it display, but it's always initializing?

Are you manipulating the child view within each parent view, before you pass it on to the next view?

Few things to make sure right off the bat:

Layout Params. Are they all set correctly? For both the parent and the child?

Parent View. The code doesn't appear to be faulty from what I can see. So is the parent view being displayed correctly?

Visibility. Are both the parent and child View.VISIBLE?

**EDIT**

Sweet. Ok, when I'm debugging these things, I like to keep it simple at first. I would take the child view, set it's background color to purple (or a contrasting color from the parent). Then, for simplicity's sake, set it's layout params to match parent. Assuming the ParentView is a FrameLayout:

```
mChildView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
mNewParentView.addView(mChildView, 
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER));
```

Does it fill up and take over the parent?

In the intermediate steps, does it no longer have a parent when it's been removed?

```
Log.d("LOGTAG", mChildView.getParent().toString());
```

Does the new parent show that the child has been added?

```
Log.d("LOGTAG", mNewParentView.getChildCount()): // before and after
```

Is it being shown 'behind' the other views within the Parent?

```
mParentView.bringChildToFront(mChildView);
```

Comment: Parent view gets displayed flawlessly. However, the child only gets displayed on the first parent. Subsequent 'parents' are blank. Yet are displayed on screen. But yep, no exceptions, executes fine. Just doesn't display how intended.

Comment: Have you ensured that the block gets executed? Because removeView(View) and addView(View) are the correct methods.

Comment: @EternalMelody Yep, they're executed.

Answer (score 0):

What may be the problem is that you are using getParent() to store oldParent. Compare for example:

```
if (view_to_move_around != null) {

    ViewGroup oldParent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.old_parent);
    if (view_to_move_around.getParent() == oldParent) {
        oldParent.removeView(view_to_move_around);
    }

} else {

// Initialise the View

}

newParent.addView(view_to_move_around)
```

Does this sound like what you're looking for? Let me know if this works.